# obsoleted package breaks yum install of older JBoss

Tags: rhel, yum, jboss

I need to install an older version of JBoss.  6.1.0 EAP is what has been approved and supported for my application.  So when I try to force install the correct version of the jboss as packages the install fails.  A number of times in the dependency resolution stage I get the following error:

```
Package shrinkwrap is obsoleted by shrinkwrap-impl-base, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
```

Then at the end I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: jbossas-modules-eap-7.2.0-8.Final_redhat_8.ep6.el6.noarch (jb-eap-6-for-rhel-6-server-rpms)
       Requires: shrinkwrap >= 1.0.0
       Available: shrinkwrap-1.0.0-14.redhat_1.ep6.el6.noarch (jb-eap-6-for-rhel-6-server-rpms)
           shrinkwrap = 1.0.0-14.redhat_1.ep6.el6
       Available: shrinkwrap-1.0.0-16.redhat_2.ep6.el6.noarch (jb-eap-6-for-rhel-6-server-rpms)
           shrinkwrap = 1.0.0-16.redhat_2.ep6.el6
```

If I try:

```
yum install shrinkwrap-1.0.0-16.redhat_2.ep6.el6.noarch
```

It changes it to `shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.1.2`.  So I'm not sure the best way to proceed.

Is it possible to force yum to install the 1.0.0 package?  If not, is it possible to install `shrinkwrap-impl-base` then install JBoss and ignore only that dependency? (there are several hundred other dependencies so I don't want to ignore all dependencies.)

Or is there some other solution?

System if RHEL 6.4 with base entitlement and `jb-eap-6-for-rhel-6-server-rpms` channel installed.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo yum --setopt=obsoletes=0 install shrinkwrap
```

Or you can put `obsoletes=0` to `/etc/yum.conf` to make such behavior persistent.

Both ways worked for me on `Oracle Linux 6.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your application certified for RHEL6?

If so, this is then a support case; and since you're paying for this, do leverage it first.

If your application isn't certified for RHEL6, then it's a learning opportunity.  "Is this *certified* for RHEL(version)" should be in the first 5 questions you ask about a given product, as you want to be able to use the support you're entitled to!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to confirm first if that older version is even available. I'm on Fedora 19, but you'd run a command similar to this:

```
$ yum list all shrinkwrap* | expand
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
shrinkwrap.noarch                            1.0.0-5.fc19                 fedora
shrinkwrap-descriptors.noarch                2.0.0-0.4.alpha2.fc19        fedora
shrinkwrap-descriptors-javadoc.noarch        2.0.0-0.4.alpha2.fc19        fedora
shrinkwrap-javadoc.noarch                    1.0.0-5.fc19                 fedora
shrinkwrap-resolver.noarch                   1.0.0-0.5.beta7.fc19         fedora
shrinkwrap-resolver-javadoc.noarch           1.0.0-0.5.beta7.fc19         fedora
```

#### Downgrading

You can use the `yum` command `downgrade` to go down to a specific version.

```
$ sudo yum downgrade shrinkwrap-1.0.0-16.redhat_2.ep6.el6.noarch
```

From the man page:

```
   downgrade
          Will try and downgrade a package from the version currently 
          installed to the previously highest version  (or  the  specified 
          version).  The depsolver will not necessarily work, but if you 
          specify all the packages it should work (thus, all the simple 
          cases will work). Also  this  does  not  work  for "installonly"  
          packages,  like Kernels. downgrade operates on groups, files, 
          provides, filelists and rpm files just like the "install" command.
```